# TSQL Issue with Table Variable using invalid column names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The issue is referencing a column name that is not within the table variable within a stored procedure.  I would assume this should have yielded an error, but it returns values instead as the column name is found in the main query.

Is this a known issue, fixed in SQL 2016 perhaps?  Or is this behavior expected?

```
DECLARE @LookupTable TABLE(MyId Integer, PRIMARY KEY(MyId));
INSERT INTO @LookupTable (MyId) Values (1);


DECLARE @DataTable TABLE(My_Id Integer, MyOtherField Char(1), PRIMARY KEY(My_Id));
INSERT INTO @DataTable (My_Id,MyOtherField) Values (1,'A');
INSERT INTO @DataTable (My_Id,MyOtherField) Values (2,'B');
INSERT INTO @DataTable (My_Id,MyOtherField) Values (3,'C');


--SELECT MyId works as expected (one row)
SELECT MyOtherField FROM @DataTable
WHERE My_Id IN (SELECT MyId FROM @LookupTable)

--SELECT My_Id should be an error
--Returns three rows when referencing a column name not in @LookupTable
SELECT MyOtherField FROM @DataTable
WHERE My_Id IN (SELECT My_Id FROM @LookupTable)

--Returns expected error: invalid column name 'My_Id'
SELECT My_Id FROM @LookupTable
```

SQL Server 2014 (SP2).

Comment: I've seen this behaviour before, in that sense it's expected... If you properly identify the columns (ie: `from @DataTable DT where DT.My_id` etc), you'll get the logically expected result.

Comment: This is totally expected. In the query you think should be an error the subquery is in fact using My_Id from @DataTable, not MyId as you think it would. This is a classic example of why it is so important to reference every single column with the table (or preferably alias) to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M_Id` column in sub-query is referred from outer table `@DataTable`. It is called correlated sub-query. The column from the outer table can be referred inside the sub-query.

Now it will make more sense.

```
SELECT MyOtherField FROM @DataTable T
WHERE T.My_Id IN (SELECT T.My_Id FROM @LookupTable)
```

Mostly the correlated sub-query are used when `exists` is used. You can see in `Where` clause the column from outer table will be referred

Comment: Of course it makes perfect sense... but when looking at a bigger piece it through me for a loop.  Had to take the blinders off this morning...

Comment: @DarianMiller - Perfectly valid question. I have seen many coming up with  similar question